# Placing four histograms into a table using R Base

Tags: r

I have four histograms that I want to show like a table. Is it possible to have a output like this:

| Histogram 1 Height | Histogram 2 Weight |
| --- | --- |
| Histogram 3 IQ | Histogram 4 Ages |

This is my data:

```
# 1.a In data height
data_height = read.table(text = "184,180,183,184,184,160,173", 
               sep=",",stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings="unknown")
data_height <- as.numeric(data_height)  # Convert data into numbers

# 1.b In data weight
data_weight = read.table(text = "70,72,85,68,90,110,84,79,76,77,80", 
               sep=",",stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings="unknown")
data_weight <- as.numeric(data_weight)  # Convert data into numbers

# 1.c In data IQ
data_iq = read.table(text = "130,105,110,107,106,109,110,112,100,119", 
               sep=",",stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings="unknown")
data_iq <- as.numeric(data_iq)  # Convert data into numbers

# 1.c In data age
data_ages = read.table(text = "17,18,17,19,18,20,22,18,34", 
               sep=",",stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings="unknown")
data_ages <- as.numeric(data_ages)  # Convert data into numbers


# 2. plot histogram (need something here to make it a table)
hist(data_height)
hist(data_weight)
hist(data_iq)
hist(data_ages)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

hist(data_height)
hist(data_weight)
hist(data_iq)
hist(data_ages)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `layout`:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE), 
       widths=c(.5,.5),heights=c(.5,.5))

layout.show(n=4)
hist(data_height)
hist(data_weight)
hist(data_iq)
hist(data_ages)
```

[image]